# How to add to SYSTEM "PATH" environment variable in windows 10 via cmd, not to user's one?

Tags: windows-10, cmd.exe, environment-variables

By using `setx "%path%;c:\whateverFolder` I just copy system path variable to users one, therefore duplicating it, and only after it the required folder is added. Is it possible to add it to SYSTEM path variable. not to the users path and if it is, how can I do it?

Comment: There is the `/M` switch of [`setx`](https://ss64.com/nt/setx.html). However, `setx` limits strings to a length of 1024 bytes, which might not be enough; and, even worse, `%PATH%` holds a concatenation of user and system `PATH` variables, so `setx` totally messes messes up with them; take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25919222) on StackOverflow...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can still use the [setx command](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/setx),
by adding the `/m` parameter:

```
/m  Specifies to set the variable in the system environment. The default setting is the local environment.
```

Like this:

```
setx /M path "%path%;C:\your\path\here\"
```